# Using fabric.js and custom fonts via web font loader

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, google-webfonts

I'm using fabric.js and a few custom fonts for my application. Fonts are loading from google via webfont loader. I need latin and cyrillic subsets.

```
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: ['Lobster::latin,cyrillic', 'Marck+Script::latin,cyrillic']
    },
    active: function() {
        var itext = new fabric.IText('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфцшщьыъэюя', {
        fontFamily: 'Lobster',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        textDecoration: 'normal',
        top: 200,
        left: 0
      });
      canvas.add(itext).renderAll();
      itext.setCoords();
})
```

When i creating IText object, his bounding box may not fit to actual text. Either boundingBox width is too big or too small. It happens not with every custom font and even not with any string lengths. Disabling object caching (like ment here https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3512 ) doesn't helps too. Here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/cheeseq/mzbck8nv/2/

Comment: You should probably open a new issue on the github project directly, as it doesn't seem to be the same as the one you linked to.